# Как сравнивать время в LocalTime учитывая конец суток?

Tags: java, алгоритм, localtime

Есть класс который делит сутки на три периода с `7:00` до `15:00`, с `15:00` до `23:00` и `23:00` до `7:00`. Это три рабочие смены, которые я должен в своем классе определять относительно текущего времени.

Используется `LocalTime`, не убежден что это хороший выбор, но лучшего пока не нашел.

С проверкой первых двух временных отрезков все просто

```
LocalTime sevenOClock = LocalTime.of(7, 0);
LocalTime fifteenOClock = LocalTime.of(15, 0);
LocalTime twentyThreeOClock = LocalTime.of(23, 0);
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();

now.isAfter(sevenOClock) && now.isBefore(fifteenOClock);
... и
now.isAfter(fifteenOClock) && now.isBefore(twentyThreeOClock);
```

А вот с последним интервалом (с `23:00` до `7:00`) загвоздка , если напишу:

```
now.isAfter(twentyThreeOClock) && now.isBefore(sevenOClock);
```

Получаится ерунда, я выкрутился таким образом:

```
public boolean isThirdShift() {
    LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();
    LocalTime twentyThreeOClock = LocalTime.of(23, 0);
    LocalTime sevenOClock = LocalTime.of(7, 0);
    LocalTime midnight = LocalTime.of(23, 59, 59);
    boolean beforeMidnightWorkTime = now.isAfter(twentyThreeOClock) && now.isBefore(midnight);
    LocalTime midnight2 = LocalTime.of(0, 0, 1);
    boolean afterMidnightWorkTime = now.isAfter(midnight2) && now.isBefore(sevenOClock);
    return beforeMidnightWorkTime || afterMidnightWorkTime;
}
```

Но это явный костыль. (Про 2 секунды которые никуда не вписываются я вообще молчу)

Подскажите как решить это нормально, может не `LocalDate` надо брать за основу или как-то привязаться к дате. Смены никак не зависят от дней недели или месяцев.

Спасибо.

Comment: int hour = LocalTime.now().plusHours(1).getHour() / 8; Не пойдет?

Comment: @Александр Поташев Не понял если честно. Прибавим час и разделим на восемь, как это даст нам ответ на вопрос какая сейчас смена?

Comment: Получим 0, 1 или 2. 0 - ночная смена, 1 - дневная, 2 - вечерняя

Comment: LocalTime.now().getHour() - я бы тоже шел по этому пути. получили в инт часы, и всего 3 варианта. этот код выносится в отдельный метод и дергаете его, передавая LocalTime, в ответ получаете инт - номер смены.